# what does the term "line" mean in the float specs?

Tags: css, css-float

I am reading through the [CSS float spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#floats) but I can't understand what the term "line" refers to or how to visualize it in my mind.

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current line.

does that refer to the "line box" term?, if that were the case, does the float create an inline formattting context?

Can you help me to understand that concept?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: line in form of text-line

Comment: yes it's the line box, if you continue reading you will find "line box" used a lot of times

Comment: In this case, the line box is any block element, for example a `<div>` element. The float does not respect the vertical flow of block element before and next to it.